# Compile error in F# nested for loop with verbose syntax

Tags: for-loop, f#, functional-programming, nested, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to F#, but when I use verbose syntax
to put a for loop in another one,
it will not compile:

```
#light "off"

let Multiple9x9 () = 
  for i in 1 .. 9 do
    printf "\n";
    for j in 1 .. 9 do
      let k = i * j;
      printf "%d x %d = %2d " i j k ;
    done;;
  done;;
Multiple9x9 ();;
printf "\n" ;;
```

I know it will work with #light "on":

```
let Multiple9x9 () = 
  for i in 1 .. 9 do
    printf "\n"
    for j in 1 .. 9 do
      let k = i * j
      printf "%d x %d = %2d " i j k
Multiple9x9 ()
printf "\n"
```

Comment: By the way you don't need `#light` anymore. Also why would you use the verbose syntax?

Comment: Maybe just that I like the feeling = =

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to use the verbose syntax you need `in` after each `let` binding. Also, you don't need `;;` after `done` in the inner loop: it makes the outer loop incomplete (cutting off the outer `done`).

Here's the corrected code:

```
let Multiple9x9 () = 
  for i in 1 .. 9 do
    printf "\n";
    for j in 1 .. 9 do
      let k = i * j in
      printf "%d x %d = %2d " i j k;
    done;
  done;;
Multiple9x9 ();;
printf "\n" ;;
```